# AWS Cloud9 EC2 won't open browser when logging into Heroku

Tags: networking, server, google-chrome, amazon-ec2

Thanks in advance,

why doesn't this work? My firewall allows incoming and outgoing connections on any port. I need to log in to Heroku . I am using Google Chrome. Running 16.04 Ubuntu. Any ideas?

```
ubuntu@ip-1-1-1-1:/home/ec2-user/environment/app$ heroku login
    heroku: Press any key to open up the browser to login or q to exit: 
    Opening browser to https://cli-auth.heroku.com/auth/browser/8a3587c4-21f3-4592-a9b2-13a64ba9c14d
     ›   Warning: Cannot open browser.
    heroku: Waiting for login... !
    JSONError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ' '
        at module.exports (/usr/local/heroku/node_modules/parse-json/index.js:26:19)
        at HTTP._parse (/usr/local/heroku/node_modules/@heroku-cli/plugin-auth/node_modules/http-call/lib/http.js:343:25)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran the command

```
$ heroku login -i
```

it let me login :D